# Access Object within Object

Tags: php, object, soap

How would I access, say, Title? I have tried $response->Element->Element1->Title but I get a NULL return.

```
array(1) {
["Element"]=>
object(stdClass)#10 (3) {
["Element1"]=>
object(stdClass)#11 (2) {
  ["Title"]=>
  string(16) "Test"
  ["Addresses"]=>
  object(stdClass)#12 (1) {
    ["Address"]=>
    object(stdClass)#13 (2) {
      ["Lines"]=>
      object(stdClass)#14 (1) {
        ["Line1"]=>
        string(17) "Test Loc"
      }
      ["PostCode"]=>
      string(7) "Postcode"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one: `Element` is not object

```
$response['Element']->Element1->Title;
```